# Insert text into iFrame in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

How would I go about inserting this text into an iframe at the caret location (and how can I make sure its plaintext; for example if they are pasting < p >< / p > it should post that in plaintext, rather than rendering the html.)?

My code. It successfully gets the selection, but I think I am making a mistake on the range part. Either way, it doesn't work.

```
iframeDocument.body.onpaste=function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 ||navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0){
pasteddata = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
 var sel = document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.window.getSelection();
range = document.getElementById('editor').contentDocument.createRange();
range.pasteHTML(pasteddata);
return false;
 }
```

Comment: can you share the HTML markup?

Comment: It will be whatever the user is copy pasting. I am interjecting the copy-paste function and replacing it with my own plain-text only version.